# getting this error EIO: i/o error in creating react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

getting this error in creating a react-app

```sh
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\react>npx create-react-app keeper
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\react\keeper.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code EIO 
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -4070
npm ERR! EIO: i/o error, read

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01- 
20T11_27_54_540Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react- 
scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting keeper/ from C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\react
Done.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New folder (2)\react
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-react-app 
keeper

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01- 
20T11_28_32_438Z- 
debug.log
```

how to solve this problem previously i am able to create react app easily
but this gives error.

Comment: What was the command used?

Comment: Try to rename the "New folder (2)" to something simple like "test", or check if you got enough free space on the disk.

Comment: npx create-react-app keeper

Comment: Thank you! I just had to rename the folder the project was within and I was able to resolve the problem.